# How to delink CloudFront from LoadBalancer and S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Currently, we are using **CloudFront** for **Load Balancer** and **S3 Bucket**. How to delink CloudFront from LoadBalancer and S3 Bucket to send all End User requests to the origin. I Deleted CloudFront distribution but I am getting a **This site can’t be reached** exception.

Comment: How do you access the website? Using CF url? it will not work obviously when CF is deleted.

Comment: you said you are using load balancer, so upon deletion of CF, go to ec2 instance navigation pane under load balancer choose your load balancer and try accessing your website using load balancer dns name.